# How to recover a pairing bluetooth pin code?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

Before i was able to connect my moto x (kitkat) with my pc with windows 7 64bits using a generic usb dongle.I remove the pairing on the phone and made it forget the pc. I tryied to connect it again and the phone asks for the pin/code and i lost it.

How to recover/ regenerate a pin code?

Comment: Remove the pairing on the PC also, then you should be able to do the setup as if it was brand new.

Comment: How do i do this ? Where i can remove pairing on windows 7 64bits ?

Comment: It somewhat depends on the specific bluetooth device.  A google search for 'remove bluetooth device windows 7' has several potentially useful articles.

Answer (score 1):

the code is auto generated by pc while you connect your mobile. and you just have to yes or i accept button on the mobile

Comment: But the connection is started by the phone, the pc is not detecting cause a problem i had before. So my phone can detect my pc but the oposite doesnot happens. If i try to connect from the phone side, it asks for the passcode/passkey and i lost it. I hope there is a way to view/restore this code from windows side, somewhere in the registry i guess, so i can connect again

Comment: make sure, your mobile is discoverable. Then search for bluetooth devices from your pc.
here is good read [add bluetooth device to pc](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/add-a-bluetooth-enabled-device-to-your-computer)